# Execute command within variable doesn't work for sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command, variable

this works for me:

```
CMD="ls -la"
$CMD
```

while this always fails:

```
CMD="sed -e 's|abc|abc|g' file"
$CMD
```

with the error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you enter the command on the command line, shell runs "expansions" on it. The last step is "Quote Removal", but it only removes quotes that weren't a result of any expansion. (See *EXPANSIONS* in `man bash` for details.) Here, the quotes are part of the variable expansion, so they're not removed.

You can enter the substitution without quotes to make it work:

```
cmd='sed -e s|abc|abc|g file'
$cmd
```